# D3 load data from varying csv data

Tags: javascript, perl, csv, d3.js

i have a temp.csv with data example as shown below. It doesn't have any group heading.

```
12,23,45,34
23,45,24,12
89,34,56,0
```

I need to load it to a variable using D3. the caveat is that data temp.csv would change often. So the data should be loaded automatically. For example the new data stored in temp.csv due to some perl script execution is changed to,

```
13,24,56,78,90,34
23,45,12,03,45,12
34,45,55,23,47,11
12,16,78,24,23,33
```

SO irrespectve of the data stored it should be loaded automatically as

```
var dataset = [
  [13,24,56,78,90,34],
  [23,45,12,03,45,12],
  [34,45,55,23,47,11],
  [12,16,78,24,23,33]
];
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Basically web client should do periodical data pooling and collect changes, or get perl [notified](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/Linux-Inotify2-1.22/Inotify2.pm) when file changes and push it to client via websocket.

Comment: This [conversation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/C4kzMIsCqDc) on Google Groups might help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `d3.csv()` to load a CSV file, see [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#wiki-csv). D3 doesn't provide any functionality to monitor something for changes, so you have to implement that yourself. As pointed out in the comments, you have basically two choices there -- have the client poll the server periodically or use some means of notifying the client that the data has changed and needs to be reloaded.

In any case, this is something D3 wouldn't help you with.

Comment: I have a click button which would initiate the data collection. SO that part is taken care of. I tired all methods in stackoverflow and google groups. It didnt help.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you have trouble loading the data using `d3.csv()`?